# IndexOptimize - Configuration

Tags: sql-server, maintenance, ola-hallengren

We recently switched to Ola Hallengren's maintenance script and automated the deployment of [*MaintenanceSolution.sql*](https://ola.hallengren.com/scripts/MaintenanceSolution.sql) to our customers's SQL Server instance.

We need to set these parameters for the job *IndexOptimize - USER_DATABASES*:

- `@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL'`
- `@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'`

I see that these parameters are present in *MaintenanceSolution.sql*:

[image]

After I change the values of the above-mentioned parameters in *MaintenanceSolution.sql* to

```
@UpdateStatistics nvarchar(max) = 'ALL'

@OnlyModifiedStatistics nvarchar(max) = 'Y'
```

then execute, I don't see either `@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL'` or `@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'` added in *Job Step properties - IndexOptimize - USER_DATABASES*:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Why don't "statistics" options appear in the job's command?
2. Is it wrong to edit *MaintenanceSolution.sql* directly for this?
3. Is there a way to add theses parameters to the job using a query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why don't "statistics" options appear in the job's command?

Because you updated the default parameter in the procedure call. This means that if you call the procedure without these parameters, E.G.

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
 @Databases ='USER_DATABASES',
 @LogToTable='Y'
```

that these default parameters  `@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL'` &  `@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'` will be used.

It is by design that these job steps are not changed.

> Is it wrong to edit *MaintenanceSolution.sql* directly for this?

Depends on your requirements.

By default no statistics will be updated when calling the procedure without the parameters specified.

If you change these `@OnlyModifiedStatistics` & `@UpdateStatistics` parameters in the procedure, all modified statistics will be updated when calling the procedure without these parameters added.

> Is there a way to add theses parameters to the job using a query?

Sure, change the jobstep to this:

```
 EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
 @Databases ='USER_DATABASES',
 @LogToTable='Y',
 @UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
 @OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y';
```

---

**EDIT**

> So even if i don't see "@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL'" &
>   "@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'" in the jobstep and that i have updated
>   it as the default parameters in the MaintenanceSolution.sql ...
>   Parameters will still be used ? –

**Sure, executing below procedure with the default `NULL` parameter for the `@UpdateStatistics` parameter runs instantly**

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@FragmentationLow = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium = NULL,
@FragmentationHigh = NULL
--,@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL'
```

Date and time start

```
Date and time: 2019-08-21 14:49:22
```

Date and time end:

```
Date and time: 2019-08-21 14:49:22
```

No stat updates statements found.

*This statement will do no index optimization and no update stats if no default parameters are changed on the procedure itself.*

**Changing the `@UpdateStatistics` parameter in the procedure and rerunning it, on a small database**

*It takes too long on all user databases ;)*

```
@UpdateStatistics nvarchar(max) = 'ALL',
```

Rerunning the procedure on one small database

Date and time start:

```
Date and time: 2019-08-21 14:50:16
```

Date and time end:

```
Date and time: 2019-08-21 14:50:23
```

One of the statements in the messages tab:

```
 UPDATE STATISTICS [Database].[dbo].[test] [UIX_dbo_test_RecordType]
```

Comment: So even if i don't see "@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL'" &  "@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'"  in the jobstep and that i have updated it as the default parameters in the MaintenanceSolution.sql ... Parameters will still be used ?

Comment: @William That is correct, if they are not specified. I added a small test to the answer :)

Comment: So to conclude, as soon as I modify the default paramters from the script, it is not necessary for me to add them in the jobstep even if i don't see them ?

Comment: @William Correct, just remember that every call will execute the proc with these default parameters unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the parameters to the job, it will just execute the SQL statement.
This is the official documentation, any parameters here you can add to the procedure, it also has some examples.
[Ola hallengren site](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)

For example this is an example that I have running now:

`EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES,
@FragmentationLow = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
@FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'`